# Add disply:swipe google font apis ip board

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to add display: swipe, google characters, i tried various ways, but i don't understand where the links are stored

```
{{if ( theme.headline_font && theme.headline_font !== 'default' ) || ( theme.body_font && theme.body_font !== 'default' ) }}
{{if theme.headline_font == theme.body_font}}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={expression="\IPS\Http\Url::encodeComponent( \IPS\Http\Url::COMPONENT_FRAGMENT, \IPS\Theme::i()->settings['body_font'] )"}:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet" referrerpolicy="origin">
{{else}}
```

thanks

Comment: Append `&display=swap` (not `swipe`) to your URL. Also, please check for typos before submitting a question, I'm sorry to say your title is a trainwreck.

Comment: sorry, I hadn't checked. thanks the code worked.